# What are some good WordPress tutorials for the php functions?

Tags: php, wordpress

I've been using WP for years but usually only coding themes in html/css and playing around with plugins a little bit.

What are some good guides/tutorials that focus more on learning and using the inbuilt php functions with WP?

Cheers in advance.

Comment: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally like the following:

> #### [WordPress Reference](http://www.dbswebsite.com/design/wordpress-reference/V3/)
>
> Template Tag Reference Guide as of Version 3.4.1

> #### [Adam Brown - WordPress Hooks Database](http://adambrown.info/p/wp_hooks)
>
> To assist website developers, this WordPress hooks database automatically scans each WP build for `apply_filters()`, `apply_filters_ref_array()`, `do_action()`, and `do_action_ref_array` to figure out exactly which hooks are available in each WordPress version and where the hooks occur.

Comment: Add this one to your list: [QueryPosts.com : better WordPress code reference](http://queryposts.com/), by one of the moderators of WP StackExchange.

Answer (score 0):

Best Collections of PHP wordpress  functions

[Common Functions](http://sixrevisions.com/wordpress/beginning-wordpress-development-a-look-at-common-functions/)

> In this guide, we will take a look at some common functions in WordPress for use in custom WordPress theme development.

[15 useful WordPress Functions](http://www.kriesi.at/archives/15-useful-wordpress-functions-you-probably-dont-know)

> While I was building my first premium WordPress Plugin, I needed to solve quite a few problems I have never encounterd when creating themes. During my research I stumbled upon several really cool wordpress functions that I want to share with you.

[25+ Extremely Useful Tricks for the WordPress Functions File](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/25-extremely-useful-tricks-for-the-wordpress-functions-file/)

> This article is targeted for WordPress theme developers. You may need have some PHP knowledge for some hacks.